# How to create a route with a dynamic value in ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data, ember-router, ember-rails

I am new to ember. If u find my question silly please dont mind.

I have a route '/lobby' which shows a different options.

when user chooses one particular option i want to create route /lobby/option_choosen(this will be the value which user chosen).

How to create route in ember in this scenario.

Comment: I shown you an approach in my answer , you can try it with [ember-twiddle.com](http://ember-twiddle.com) and update your question if you find any issue in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read ember guide [dynamic segment part](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments) for defining routes. and for model preparing you can read [dynamic model](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models) .

In router.js,

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('lobbies');
  this.route('lobby', { path: '/lobby/:lobby_id' });
});
```